# ListViewItem Construction

Tags: c#, listview, constructor, listviewitem

Quick and easy question on construction.

I have the following code for adding an Item to a list view.

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
item.Text = file;
item.SubItems.Add("Un-Tested");
lvJourneys.Items.Add(item);
```

However I wish to use code more similar to the following, but i'm unable to find the correct syntax,

```
lvJourneys.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(file, "Un-Tested"));
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Write a function to do it. And one to accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make your own custom constructor like such:

```
public ListViewItem(string receivedFile, string theItem){ //I assume File is of type String
     this.Text=receivedFile;
     this.SubItems.Add(theItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a factory

```
static class ListViewItemFactory
{
    public static ListViewItem Create(string text,string subItem)
    {
       ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
       item.Text = text;
       item.SubItems.Add(subItem);
       return item;
    }
}
```

And then use

```
lvJourneys.Items.Add(ListViewItemFactory.Create(file, "Un-Tested"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your own ListViewItem to add a new constructor

```
public class ItemWithSubItem:ListViewItem
{
  public ItemWithSubItem(string ItemText, string SubItemText)
  {
     this.Text=ItemText;
     this.SubItems.Add(SubItemText);
  }
}
```

Then you can just use

```
lvJourneys.Items.Add(new ItemWithSubItem(file, "Un-Tested"));
```